# connection refused (os error 111) using python selenium & geckodriver

Tags: debian, selenium

i am quit new to webscraping, i am building a personal app with python on debian buster and firefox geckodriver as follow, the server is online

```
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
driver.get(url)
```

i aim to triggered this app by a ajax call in a web page, it's a nginx server so the py script is called in a php exec command :

```
exec ('/usr/bin/python3 webdriver.py');
```

it works fine in command line in debian if i am logged in root or another user.
when i call the script using web interface, the user is www-data and i encounter this error : ***connection refused (os error 111)***

i ve been searching for 3 days in all internet sources i can find and tried all i could, i haven't any solution for now

would you have any idea of the way to solve this issue?

Edit :

- selenium version 3.141.0
- Mozilla Firefox 78.8.0esr
- geckodriver 0.29
- geckodriver.log for www-data user (with error):

  - 1614703595351   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:53899
  - 1614703595556   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile22XajP"
  - *** You are running in headless mode.
- geckodriver.log for for admin (without error) :

  - 1614702846828   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:46897
  - 1614702847019   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile7jTA4y"
  - *** You are running in headless mode.
  - 1614702859057   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 45145
  - 1614702859109   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
  - JavaScript warning: https://..........................js?v=1.2.7199.0, line 119: unreachable code after return statement
  - JavaScript warning: https://..........................js?v=1.2.7199.0, line 119: unreachable code after return statement
  - 1614702872140   Marionette      WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 500 ms: stacktrace:
  - TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:245:13
  - TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:230:10
  - Interaction.flushEventLoop@chrome://marionette/content/interaction.js:416:10
    webdriverClickElement@chrome://marionette/content/interaction.js:182:31
  - 1614702900530   Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 45145
- geckodriver.log for www-data with geckodriver 0.21 :

  - 1614706982655   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
  - 1614706982680   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:33947
  - 1614706983553   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.p37a7r0syAmR"
  - *** You are running in headless mode.
  - (firefox-esr:22409): dconf-CRITICAL **: 17:44:03.845: unable to create directory '/var/www/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! Your question doesn't tell which address and port your program is trying to access. "Connection refused" often means that there is no listener at the given address and port combination. It can also mean that a firewall actively refuses your connection attempt. When launched from the command line, your program may use a different address/port combination than when launched from the web page. It is your job to find out which address/port it uses in both cases. Or the networking environment of the web page is different from the Debian command line.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i should have precise the geckodriver.log

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on an Ubuntu server. It looks like Marionette doesn't start when using the www-data user but there is no error either.
You can get rid of the permission denied issue by creating /var/www/.cache and giving it to www-data but that won't help your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a permissions problem.
www-data's home dir is /var/www which is usually owned by root.

You can either give /var/www to www-data or, to limit permission changes, you can create /var/www/.mozilla and change its ownership to www-data. Then try running your script again.

What seems to be happening is Firefox is trying to save the user preferences and failing. It reports no error nor does it fully crash its main process but is still being limited enough to not be able to communicate with geckodriver.

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/695824

Comment: thank you very much for these answers, sure it's a permission problem.
digging it..

Comment: Doing `mkdir -p /var/www/.cache /var/www/.mozilla` worked for me! Thank you @madj

Answer (score 0):

yeaaa it works fine
thanks a lot

i just created the following directories:
/var/www/.cache
/var/www/.mozilla

i gave www-data permission to write in it.

i m wondering if ther is not a security problem with this.
maybe should be better to specify a working directory for mozilla somewhere else..

Comment: I think you're fine security-wise because those dirs will be specific to your selenium scripts and not shared with other users/processes.
If you want to be extra safe, you can delete the contents of the .cache directory after each run in case firefox stores something sensitive there (depending on what you're doing).

Comment: @madj - Thank you for nice question. It helped me. Also, just to follow the StackOverflow best practices. I request you to delete this answer! Using comment & accepting answer is usually more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is `.cache` and `.mozilla` folders, which need permissions. The data is generated in the profile of the user who execute the script.

This solution worked for me:

1. Identify the user who needs to save the cache. In my case it was
   **www-data** (the user of [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)). I checked it in the folder `/tmp/`.
   You can see the owner of folders like
   `/tmp/Temp-276cddf8-d7c5-4a09...` These folders are generated by
   Firefox.
2. The user needs bash permissions, so you have to adjust the file
   `/etc/passwd` from
   `www-data:33:33:www-data:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin` to `www-data:x:33:33:www-data:**/var/www**:**/bin/bash**`
3. Create the folders in the path, in my case is `/var/www/` (this path
   is located in the user path specified in the file `/etc/passwd`).

`mkdir /var/www/.cache`

`mkdir /var/www/.mozilla`

`chown www-data:www-data .cache`

`chown www-data:www-data .mozilla`

---

@sdragnev answered correctly, but in my case I still needed to give bash permission to the user.